# Images do not show on mobile devices but they display and work fine on desktops and if "Desktop site" is turned on

Tags: css, mobile, desktop, cloudinary

I built this site using phugo (a Hugo theme) and am also using Cloudinary to host the images so they will dynamically be reduced on various device widths. Well, that's supposed to be the plan.

I do not see the thumbnails in Chrome on my S9 yet the larger image appears if I click on the blank area where the image(s) should be.

When activating "Desktop site" everything works.

I'm stumped. There are too many variables for me to tinker with. Could be Cloudinary? The main.js that came w the theme? My meta tags? CSS? ... S.O.S. Mayday Help! TY

Site: https://portfolio.infin80.com/branding-marketing-graphic-designer-david-grant-portfolio.html

Edit (6/14/19 2pm PST): I'm nearly certain it's not the CSS

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet that will help others to help out to you

Comment: Your images are huge - use a width parameter to reduce them to a saner size, like maybe 800 pixels e.g. https://res.cloudinary.com/infin80/image/upload/t_portsm,f_auto,dpr_auto,q_auto/las-vegas-brand-marketing-specialists-logo-web-design should be https://res.cloudinary.com/infin80/image/upload/t_portsm,f_auto,dpr_auto,q_auto,w_800/las-vegas-brand-marketing-specialists-logo-web-design . this will make your site load faster and be easier on the browser.